# Chrome QR Code Scanner on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Google released a new feature for Google Chrome 61 on mobile where they provide you with a built in QR Code Scanner which works very well and its only available on your keyboard if you focus the URL Bar on your mobile device.

I would like to ask you if you think that there is a possibility to trigger that scanner or have it as an option when you focus an input on your webpage. Allowing you to add information in that input by scanning a QR Code.

Here is a link, if you did`t got the chance to try the feature: https://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Chrome-for-iOS-gets-updated-with-built-in-QR-code-scanner_id90688